# How to redirect Python print commands to putty SSH console?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, putty

after many unsuccessful researches I've decided to ask my question here so maybe someone will provide me an answer or a lead for a problem I got.

I have a Python script that runs as a background process on an embedded device (the OS is a Linux distro). This script do important measurements and because of that, it can not be terminated or restarted.

I was wondering if it was possible to implement a chunk of code that will redirect the print() outputs to a Putty SSH console when we send it a command via a messaging protocol (MQTT).

So the situation will be like this:

- Device receive a command, set a variable to 1
- Print() outputs will now be visible on the current root session opened by Putty SSH client.

I don't know if it is possible but I'm opened to suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your answers, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This sounds like a heavily "specialized" solution. Wouldnt it be easier to have your python script to some file space (probably in some "rotating" way to avoid filling precious space) and "tail -f" that file when logging in?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session

Comment: Ok thx I think I'll do this

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by GhostCat, I've decided to go for a logging solution so anyone who can connect to the device by SSH can just "tail -F" the log file and see the debug messages.

I've removed all the print() statements in the code and replaced them by logging calls (which is, indeed, a more professional approach)

If someone had the same question as I, you can read this : http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/

or this : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

to help you solve your issue.

Thanks again to GhostCat and Tripleee for their help.